# Stamp effect in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to follow this adobe tutorial : https://helpx.adobe.com/fr/illustrator/how-to/stamp-effect-illustrator.html

However, it seems there is a problem with the actual AI version. Indeed, when applied, the stamp effect removes the white grain, and the texture is fully black, without the desired effect.

Does anyone know how to use the stamp effect efficiently?

Comment: Even though size is usually not an issue with vector art, this tutorial employs raster effects. A lot of these effects are greatly affected by the scale of the art. Try decreasing or increasing the size of the art to see of you get different results.

Comment: You aren't using a raster image are you?.. placed into Illustrator and then trying the tutorial? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the tutorial with AI CC 2018, and it appears to work. My French isn't perfect, and some menu items seem to be located in different places in the user interface, but I still managed to work it out.

Make sure you have the artwork selected, apply the Stamp effect, and try adjusting the settings for the Stamp effect, until you can see the white grain.

Here are the settings I used.

Light/Dark Balance: 9

Smoothness: 1

I think the tutorial says to use Light/Dark 1, and Smoothness 6, but that gives me too few white grains.  I don't know if this is just a mistake in the tutorial, or because of differences in Illustrator versions.

[image]

Comment: What ever the scale, it doesn't work for me... maybe I will reinstall the software...

Comment: Make sure your raster resolution is set high enough. Try increasing the DPI of your raster effects in the "Effects > Document Raster Effect Settings" menu

Comment: Yes, I'm always at 300 dpi !

Comment: @Foaly i have never seen reinstalling illustrator do any good. But deleting your preferences can be beneficial (uninstalling does not reset prefs)